# Signup form, placeholder is acting like input

Tags: html, forms

A client of mine has come to me with an error on his website's signup form.

Please see [this url](http://www.graphictankclients.co.uk/brunch/register/) for an example.

All of the fields marked with an a asterisk is required but the placeholders in some (Date of birth, Flat / House number, etc.) are acting as input and allowing the form to be submitted without and actual content being entered.

Does anyone have any idea of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use "real" placeholders (+ modernizr), instead of faking it. But to solve your problem you could check the `value` against its `defaultValue`. You could also do this on the inputs instead of hard-coding the values.

```
if (input.value !== input.defaultValue && (otherchecks))
```

And for emptying the input you could use this instead of checking for a hard-coded value

```
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
```

Comment: I tried using onblur / onfocus but it gave the same error. What do you mean by "real" placeholders?

Comment: only using the "placeholder" attribute and not messing around with onblur/onfocus - if you need IE<9 compatibility I suggest modernizr or similiar.